# Always goes into the first case, can anyone explain?

Tags: android

1.I am trying to create a higher or lower game on Android studio, and for some reason it always goes into the first case only.
2.The application runs, but would not give the desired output.

```
package com.sanpochi.higherorlowergame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  int n;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(20)+1;
  }

  public void Guess(View view) {
    EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);
    int numb = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());

    if (n < numb) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Higher!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (n > numb) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lower!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are correct!! Congrats!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove int from this line `int n = rand.nextInt(20)+1;`
let it be

```
n = rand.nextInt(20)+1;
```

the random number generated in onCreate will not be used in public void Guess(View view) {} as the scope of the variable n gets restricted.

Comment: Or in other words: the way things are now, the *field* n will always have the value 0. So every time the user did not type in "0", the comparison in `Guess() ` will run into the first branch.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int n;
this n will be used in the method Guess(), because the scope if this variable is Global to this activity. You can use / manipulate this variable from anywhere within this activity.

if the variable is defined inside a method, then it's scope is restricted to just that method.

As things are now, yes variable n will be having a some fixed value, that will be not changed.

Comment: that is correct. it works. I was initializing the variable n again in the random number generator!

Answer (score 0):

> ... and for some reason it always goes into the first case only.

In WHERE used the function `Guess()`? How do know this? The `onCreate` function doing almost nothing related to your main idea.

And the question 2 is done by the same issue.